# Series of ratios of sums of geometric terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Is there a general procedure for evaluating series of the form:

$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{a_1 p_1^t+\cdots+a_m p_m^t}{b_1 q_1^t+\cdots+b_n q_n^t},$$

where $a_1,\dots,a_m,p_1,\dots,p_m,b_1,\dots,b_n,q_1,\dots,q_n\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$?

You may assume that the series converges.

Comment: I would say no. Even something relatively benign like
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^t+3^t}{4^t+5^t}
$$ is not known to have a closed-form.

Comment: Interesting! Are there at least reliable numerical methods for evaluating such series?

Comment: One approach: WLOG $q_1$ is the biggest; then you could split it up into $m$ sums, say $1\leq j\leq m$, each of which looks like $ a_j \sum_{t} p_j ^t / (b_1 q_1^t +\cdots + b_n q_n^)$. Then maybe you could use theorems like the the Integral Test remainder, or compare with appropriate geometric series (crassly, something like $\frac{a_j}{b_j}\sum_{t} (p_j / q_1)^t$), or use various accelerated convergence formulas.